# How to get and code for API in PayPal in HTML through jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a web developer. I am working on PayPal. I did the code for PayPal transaction through 'Bay Now' button using script

, but I and user, both not getting any Email from PayPal after payment. Is there any other process through which user get email automatically after PayPal payment.

I also want to code for 'Check Out with PayPal' button in HTML through javascript or jquery and how to get API and code for API in HTML through javascript or jquery.

Comment: Ask PayPal tech. support. They know the answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup your IPN script yet @ your server?

Have you enabled IPN's and set the address to your IPN script @ PayPal?

To check IPN Settings go to..

Profile > My Selling Tools > Instant payment notifications (update)

[PayPal IPN Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

[PayPal IPN PHP Class](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN)

[PayPal IPN Example](http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes I have set the IPN (notificatin URL)

Comment: but its not getting any response

Comment: Is the URL pointing to a .php file that contains something similar to what the example in the response I posted above has? Also you can view your IPN history, the link is @ the IPN edit page. This may provide some helpful info as well. Also here is the [PayPal IPN Testing Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/)

Comment: I am not working in PHP. I need in Jquery or JS and I also read all the process of link 1st that you send me. I getting problem in how to call the method DoExpressCheckoutPayment and other methods in HTML in JS or jquery

Comment: Ah, that's your problem... PayPal's IPN services operates on the back-end or server-side. Javascript is a front-end or client-side language. You'll need to utilize php, python, ruby, or a similar language to utilize the IPN system.

Comment: I am using the BB code to process the data. Is it possible to do it in  this code.

Comment: You're referring to bulletin board code right? That's not a programming language, just a markup language to format posts in a forum. Your best bet will be to check out the examples posted above, work your way through that in PHP and post questions as needed.